# "+-1" in the trophy display for reputation changes, possible bug?

Tags: bug, reputation

I was browsing through Meta StackOverflow, and I came across this:
[image]

I had performed this action a few days ago (June 16, 2019), and it had decremented my reputation that moment but it suddenly popped up now (June 20, 2019) and notified as "+-1". I'm using firefox browser v67.0.2 (64-Bit).

Comment: It seems all the three questions I came across, the marked one and the cross-site question on meta-so, all were posted quite recently. I should've gone through them before posting this question. Sorry.

Comment: The UTC time on the other questions are really close, it seems it happened to many people on the site.